# Nearest Neighbor Recommendation System w/ categorical variables

Tags: clustering, recommender-system, similarity, distance, one-hot-encoding

I would like to build a recommendation system:

- no ratings are available at the time of recommendation, therefore only a purely context-based recommendation system is needed
- as input features answers of a questionnaire are available (all categorical)

My idea is the following:

- Find the most similar users based on the answers from the questionnaire with a suitable distance measure.
- the past recommendations of these users are relevant and meaningful for the new user in the system

---

When choosing the encoding and distance measure, I have the problem that there are only categorical variables with values from binary to questions with 20 unique values.
One-hot encoding has its drawbacks with multicollinearity and I'm not sure since variables with 20 unique possibilties get such a strong emphasis.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a possible approach?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Clustering Categorical Data using Gower distance (in Python):  [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/halflingwizard/clustering-categorical-data-using-gower-distance)

Answer (score 1):

In r there is a package called `dprep` and it holds a magical method call `knngow()`. This is a KNN algorithm which uses the gower distance (not a physical distance like Euclidean or Manhattan).

It is specifically useful for working with nominal and ordinal variables that translate into binary or leveled factors because it is able to manage & differentiate between the regular interval between levels in a variable without being biased by ranks.

There is a dearth of good tutorials or information on it, but it is a solid step in the right direction for you because it solves the distance dilemma under the hood.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dprep/index.html Package ‘dprep’ was removed from the CRAN repository. --> Why?